# OpenCV 4.1.0 Android Sdk unable to find a matching configuration Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to import OpenCV 4.1.0 Android sdk to my android studio project and get gradle build error (build successed with OpenCV 4.0.1 Android SDK).

```
Unable to find a matching variant of project :opencv:
  - Variant 'debugApiElements':
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
      - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
  ...
```

Here are my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ml.nopain.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':opencv')
}
```

And my opencv build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.opencv"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

When i try to import OpenCV 4.0.1 Sdk, gradle build successed without any errors. 
What can I try to do to solve the problem? Thanks for your help!

**Solution**
Thanks to Ranjan Kumar, i've found the solution for this problem! Just change 'com.android.application' to 'com.android.library'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on gradle it appears that you are trying to build opencv as app. You shall make opencv as module(library) and include in your actual app.

There is one guide for integrating opencv with android.
https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

Comment: just edit 'com.android.application' to 'com.android.library'